# Finding new coordinates on Mouse Up for Marker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I am using [this element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map?active=google-map-marker) for my map. I want to detect when the cursor moves, to find out the new coordinates and write them in a hidden field.

The problem is that I don't get the coordinates of the place where the marker has fallen, but the coordinates from the place it was before. So if I move the marker 3 times, the input fields are always one step behind

**Javascript (Precompiled in Coffeescript)**

```
window.map    = document.querySelector 'google-map'
window.marker = $(map).find("google-map-marker").get(0)

if map
    marker.mouseEvents = true;
    marker.clickEvents = true;
    marker.addEventListener "google-map-marker-mouseup", onGoogleMarkerMouseUp


onGoogleMarkerMouseUp = (e)->
    # Like this, it gives the old coordinates
    updateBookPosition e.target.longitude, e.target.latitude
```

**HTML (ERB rails template)**

```
<google-map zoom="<%= zoom %>" longitude="<%= longitude %>" latitude="<%= latitude %>">
    <google-map-marker id="marker" longitude="<%= longitude %>" latitude="<%= latitude %>" draggable="<%= draggable %>"></google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```